# Minimum compatible version of cocoa pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

How to check what version of cocoa pods I need for latest version of SDK that is available.

I need this [SDK](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKCoreKit) and I also use another libraries from pods that require cocoapods -v 0.38.2

Where can I check the version of cocoa pods which is compatible with FBSDKCoreKit 4.10.1?

I know that the last version 0.39.0 is compatible with it, but my question is what's the oldest one is available for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they [specified](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#cocoapods_version) the `spec.cocoapods_version` tag (which they [didn't](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec)) in their `podspec` file you have no way of knowing.

Comment: Oh, got it, in any case it helpful to know how to find this information) thanks!